# Azure B2C sign-up. Hide password fields until verification code entered?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure B2C Sign Up page, is there a way to have all the password and "display name" fields hidden until the verification code has been successfully entered and verified?

We've read this page on what customisations can be done:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization
and it states JavaScript is not allowed.

So wondering if there's another way to accomplish this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At this time there is no way to only show the password and user attributes fields after the verification code experience has complete.**

You can request this specific feature in the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](http://aka.ms/aadb2cuv) or vote for the more generic ["Add support for JavaScript inside the custom UI branding page" feedback entry](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br).

Comment: Update - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own JavaScript client-side code to your Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) B2C applications. Below article describes how you can change your user flow or custom policy to enable script execution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples#javascript-samples

Sample javascript code to show/hide password input item

```js
function makePwdToggler(pwd){
  // Create show-password checkbox
  var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  var id = pwd.id + 'toggler';
  checkbox.setAttribute('id', id);

  var label = document.createElement('label');
  label.setAttribute('for', id);
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('show password'));

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild(checkbox);
  div.appendChild(label);

  // Add show-password checkbox under password input
  pwd.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', div);

  // Add toggle password callback
  function toggle(){
    if(pwd.type === 'password'){
      pwd.type = 'text';
    } else {
      pwd.type = 'password';
    }
  }
  checkbox.onclick = toggle;
  // For non-mouse usage
  checkbox.onkeydown = toggle;
}

function setupPwdTogglers(){
  var pwdInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=password]');
  for (var i = 0; i < pwdInputs.length; i++) {
    makePwdToggler(pwdInputs[i]);
  }
}

setupPwdTogglers();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: For me it is not clear where to put the javascript code. I understood that would be possible to add a javascript code without create an entire customize page. But I did not find how to do it. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow

"*You can embed your JavaScript* or you can link to external JavaScript files."